# Why do I have an SD card but still no storage space?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, insufficient-memory

I have a textbook Android tablet and an SD card, but when I try to download apps like Viber and other apps, they say I have insufficient space and my tablet is saying "Storage space is running out. Some system functions may not work".

Comment: [How to save files to external SD card on a non-rooted Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526) - [How to move apps from internal to external storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214568/218526)

Answer (score 0):

The storage used to store apps is internal storage. Android doesn't allow apps to be installed on the SD card so no matter how big your SD card is. Your tablet will install apps in the tablet's internal storage.
You can move apps to an SD card using App2SD or in the phone settings, but only apps that allow moving to SD will be movable. If the app doesn't allow App2SD, you can't move it.

There is some advanced workaround to use an ext4 partition on your SD card as a `/data` partition, but it needs to be enabled at the kernel level.

Answer (score 0):

Android versions less than 6.0 don't natively support using an external SD card to 'extend' the internal SD card, therefore, only data can be moved to the SD card if it has been allowed by the app author.

To move this data to the SD card, you can go to Settings > Apps and select the app which you want to move to the SD card, and press 'Move to SD'. If the option is greyed out, it means the author has not allowed 'moving to the SD card'. You can move the data back by pressing 'Move to phone'.

Comment: Hmmm... are you sure?  On at least some KitKat devices, when you move an app without any data to the external card using the method you describe, the internal storage is increased significantly.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was enable the Developers in settings, then scrolled down to enable the setting that says to override apps that don't allow transfer to SD card.

Every single app I have, including internal or the ones that came with my Samsung Galaxy J7 2017 (well, most) are on my SD. My internal storage still says it's halfway full. But I believe that is Samsung in itself.

After enabling that setting, you will need to go into app info after installing the said app, then manually transfer from the device or internal storage to external or SD storage.